# + Operator for Dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The plus-operator ('+') seems to have multiple functions for Date-type objects in javascript. The following input gives different output for +t:

```
var t = new Date();
console.log('the date is '+t);
console.log(+t);
```

More confusing for me is that it doesn't convert to millseconds here:

```
console.log(t+5);
```

And especially:

```
console.log(5+t);
```

Since:

```
console.log(+t+5);
```

I'm surprised it treats the fives as strings, and that '+t' semantically different between +t+5 and t+5.

Is there a reference where I can find what operators have what impact on Date objects? That way I can get some confidence that the multiplicity of behaviors for + is implemented the same in each browser.

Quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqQv7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unary '+' operator (+x) is just a way to convert an expression into a number. All other combinations are either implicit number or string conversions. There is no special overloading of the '+' operator for Date.

The closest thing to a complete reference about how exactly Javascript operators work is the ECMAScript standard:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

For a less complicated overview, you might want to have a look at the Mozilla reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference#Operators

Answer (score 4):

`+new Date()` is the same as `Number(new Date())`. It simply converts to a number using type conversion.

Comment: No, it doesn't convert String to a Number in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an important notice regarding `+` (an addition operator) in the [standard](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1):

> No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive [when type-coercing an object]. All native ECMAScript objects except Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; **Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint String were given.**

And that's what happens when you attempt to evaluate `new Date() + 5` expression. The left operand should become a *String*, not a Number - and `toString` is called, not `valueOf`.

On the contrary, this...

`+new Date() + 5`

... explicitly sets the left operand's type to Number (by calling `valueOf` method, which in case of Date returns that milliseconds' value). This is done *before* evaluating binary plus operation, because unary plus precedence is higher.

---

As a sidenote, the order of operands in `+` operation doesn't matter in JS: `t + 5` and `5 + t` are equivalent. And if `t` is a String (or type-coerced to a String), `+` will be treated as a concatenation operator, not an addition one.

Comment: Interesting. But why isn't (5+t) treated as a hint for the Date to be type-coerced to Number?

Comment: Because otherwise `+` operation would have become non-commutative - and that's considered a greater evil when dealing with weak types.

Comment: So I guess 5+(+t)! Thanks.. It does make sense now. I'll stick to Number() instead of the unary +.

Comment: Yes, 5 + + t would be treated that way. However, `5 ++ t` will cause a Syntax Error (`invalid increment operator`).

Comment: touché on the ++, hahah.